# Instantiating C# Classes in Lua

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface

I am writing a scripting engine for my game using the LuaInterface library.  I am getting an error when attempting to instantiate the class in Lua. The error is:

```
"./Scripts/sv_worldgen.lua:2: attempt to call global 'Campfire' (a string value)"
```

Where sv_worldgen.lua is (in entirety):

```
function GenerateChunk(worldChunk, chunkGridPosition)
    tf = Campfire()
    tf:SetPosition(chunkGridPosition)
end
```

`Campfire` is a class in C#, and appears to be exposed to lua as per the [CLRPackage example](https://github.com/stevedonovan/MonoLuaInterface/blob/master/bin/lua/CLRPackage.lua) and of course the [LuaInterface Reference](http://penlight.luaforge.net/project-pages/penlight/packages/LuaInterface/).  I cannot seem to get around this error, and I have done due diligence of searching.  The only other behavior of the script I can manage throws a similar error, but where it is `"(a table value)"`.  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you in advance!

*I tried explicitly doing `Campfire._ctor()`, but `_ctor()` is a string value.*

Comment: How are you exposing your class to lua? How are you loading it in lua?

Comment: `LoadScript("sh_CLRPackage.lua")` and then `import "JASG"`.  I have updated the question.  This is now telling me that `Campfire` is a string value.

Comment: you're going to have to show how Campfire is exposed to Lua. Without that, it is impossible to say.

Comment: @Schollii `lua["Campfire"] = typeof(Campfire);` gives me that Campfire is a userdata value.  If I leave that out and let luainterface do its job of accessing my assembly classes, the error is on the next line with `"attempt to call method 'SetPosition' (a string value)"`

Comment: Maybe the problem is at the C# level. Show the minimal .cs that produces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by using CLRPackage and using it to first load the assembly.

```
//Lua
JASG = CLRPackage("JASG", "JASG")
```

Then and only then can you link the classname to the actual C# class using (this must be done before trying to access it in Lua):

```
//Lua
Campfire=JASG.Campfire;
```

and then normal instantiation can occur by

```
//Lua
cf = Campfire()
```